# PHP - SMTP Error 10060 (SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server)

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I using SMTP connection to send email. It is not working from last one month before that it was working properly. I am not able to get the actual reason of that error.

Error is:

```
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: A connection attempt failed because the 
connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established 
connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (10060)
```

My code is :

```
$mail->SMTPDebug    = 1;
$mail->SMTPAuth     = true;    // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure   = "ssl";   // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host         = "smtp.gmail.com";   // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port         = 465;   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username     = "emailid@gmail.com";// GMAIL username
$mail->Password     = "xxxxxxx";// GMAIL password
$mail->AddAddress("somthing@gmail.com", "Somthing");
$mail->Subject  = "Test Subject";
$mail->AltBody  = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
$mail->MsgHTML(utf8_decode("HTML Content"));
$mail->Send();
```

Comment: Have you tried the debug steps at [https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78775?hl=en]?

Comment: can you try this `$Mail->Port = 587;`

Comment: @ling.s Port 587 is TLS but google also accepts Port 25 for ssl security

Comment: @ling.s Thanks for you reply, as you suggested `$Mail->Port = 587;` for `SSL` or `TLS`?

Comment: can you try `$Mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';` instead of `utf8_decode`

Comment: @ling.s i tried `$Mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';` also but still same error.

Comment: Have you changed the password of the google account? (sometimes there is an easy solution^^)

Comment: I think `$mail->MsgHTML(utf8_decode("HTML Content"));` is issue, but I'm not sure. Shall I post a working example?

Comment: I think you should use PHP MAILER.

Comment: @P0rnflake I changed the password 9-10 month ago.

Comment: Is the server yours ? Your ISP or Hosting Company could be blocking those ports